# Aggregation $out stage creates collection, all queries return TypeError: db.collection.. is not a function

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas, mongo-shell, mongodb-compass

My goal is to create a materialized view using an aggregation on an existing collection. I was following [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPj7oBGaTZI&list=PL4RCxklHWZ9tKWSS21BmtFxOs51f-l1o9&index=28) - Materialized Pre-Aggregations for Exploratory Analytics Queries. There's an accompanying [Github repo](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/cubes/tree/main)

I've created my pipeline, ran it and a collection was created. However, any attempt to run a query against it in the shell throws an error.

I've tried these approaches:

1. **MongoDB Compass Aggregation Pipeline Builder**
2. **`mongosh` shell**

Both created a collection, which I verified via the Compass UI, the Atlas UI and the `mongosh` shell. It's visible when running the command `db.getCollectionNames` and `getCollectionInfos` and it's visible in both Compass and Atlas.
[running `db.getCollectionNames()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVdWt.png)
[collection info from `db.getCollectionInfos`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpjpE.png)

Running `db.stats.findOne()` outputs this:
`TypeError: db.stats.findOne is not a function`

This is the pipeline

```
[
  {
    $addFields:
      {
        processed: {
          $dateFromString: {
            dateString: {
              $replaceOne: {
                input:
                  "$__dc_process.last_updated",
                find: "@",
                replacement: "",
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
  },
  {
    $sort:
      {
        processed: -1,
      },
  },
  {
    $group:
      {
        _id: {
          campaign: "$_projectId",
          bot: "$bot",
          "render-status": "$render-status",
          "stream-status": "$stream.status",
          processor: "$__dc_process.satellite",
        },
        "total": {
          $count: {},
        },
        "last_updated": {
          $first: "$processed",
        },
        "last_updated_job": {
          $first: "$$ROOT",
        },
      },
  },
  {
    $out: "stats",
  },
]
```

I've tried disconnecting and reconnecting the shell. In the UI for Compass and Atlas, querying does work and returns a result, but I can't replicate in the shell.

I'm not really sure if the fact that the `group` stage is not first has any effect? The presenter notes that you should not do any filtering beforehand, but I haven't done that here.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
`db.stats` is a method on `db`, so my collection name collides.
[the solution to this very specific problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I21In.png)